# Getting full nexus archive name in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, nexus

I'm trying to set-up jenkins build pipeline. It should contains three steps:

1. Build project
2. Publish artifact to nexus
3. Deploy artifact to host

Step 2 should trigger step 3 with full nexus artifact name as a parameter. I don't know how to obtain that value.

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer{
            repository(url: "hereMyNexusRepo") {
                authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
            }
            pom.version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
            pom.artifactId = "artifactId"
            pom.groupId = "groupId"
            pom.packaging='jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Artifact published by this task has a name that is concatenation of 3 known values:

1. groupId
2. artifactId
3. version

and unknown values

1. date
2. time

Sample artifact path looks as follow:

```
groupId/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-1.0-20170323.225852-2.jar
```

How can I get this path? Or can I override it from Jenkins?